# Meaning of "même" in "Mon affaire suivait son cours, selon l’expression même du juge"

Tags: sens, adverbes

The question is on *même* in the following excerpt from The Stranger by Camus.

> Il semblait que le juge ne s’intéressât plus à moi et qu’il eût classé mon cas en quelque sorte. Il ne m’a plus parlé de Dieu et je ne l’ai jamais revu dans l’excitation de ce premier jour. Le résultat, c’est que nos entretiens sont devenus plus cordiaux. Quelques questions, un peu de conversation avec mon avocat, les interrogatoires étaient finis. Mon affaire suivait son cours, selon l’expression **même** du juge.

**Question**

1. Does it modify *l’expression* or *du juge* (or perhaps *juge* or *le juge*)?
2. And what does it mean?

**Background**

Here are the sources of my difficulty:

- According to the examples [in this dictionary entry](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/meme), *même* can come before or after the thing it modifies.
- It has a number of senses that might work here.  For instance, *the **very** expression used by the magistrate*, or *the expression of the magistrate **himself***, or perhaps something about the ***same*** expression or the ***same*** magistrate (though these last don't seem likely because there is but one expression and one magistrate in question).
- The English translations I have give no effect to *même*.

Please explain the thought process, if possible, that gives us the right sense; whether we are relying on a rule (*the same expression* can only be *la même expression* maybe?) or on context.

Comment: Moderator note: the question is about understanding the French expression, not how to express it in English, which we are not experts in.

Answer (score 2):

*Même* est ici un adverbe signifiant : ***exactement, précisément***

Pour comprendre le sens de la phrase on peut le remplacer par un adjectif :

> ... selon l’expression *exacte* (ou *précise*) du juge.

Mais si on le remplace par un autre adverbe, cela ne fonctionne pas, car *même* fait souvent partie des tournures idiomatiques :

> ... selon l'expression "exactement" du juge. (incorrect)

---

<sup>*Référence issue du petit Robert*</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Then it modifies *la* (forming *exactly the expression*)? Would it be wrong to call it an adjective modifying *expression* (forming *the exact expression*)? Or maybe I am totally off-base, and *même* modifies *de* (meaning *exactly of the magistrate* and not from any other source)? Or maybe it works like a (e.g. German) particle and casts an air of exactness on the whole sentence? I am not suggesting these things all mean very different things. I just want to learn the exact syntactic structure.

Comment: *Même* placé après un nom ou un pronom est un adverbe qui modifie le mot qui le précède. Comme il fait souvent partie d'idiomes, il est très difficile de lui substituer un autre adverbe. J'ai substitué *même* par un adjectif pour permettre de comprendre comment un francophone utilise ce mot, 'même' si ce n'est exact du point de vue grammatical... --- *Même* (adjectif & adverbe) est un mot difficile à employer, ce sont surtout les exemples qui aident à en acquérir la maîtrise.

Answer (score 1):

Même est simplement un adjectif, dans son sens "exactement".

> Placé directement après un nom ou un pronom, souligne l'identité, la
>   spécificité de la personne ou de la chose dont on parle. Ceux-là mêmes
>   qui l'avaient soutenu l'abandonnent aujourd'hui. C'est cela même. Ce
>   sont ses paroles mêmes. L'incident s'est produit le jour même de son
>   départ.

voir: http://cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/m%C3%AAme